# Histogram not showing all x-axis labels in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have graphed a histogram but for some reason the x labels are partial.
[image]

I want to have every year written on the x-axis. Here is my code:

`ggplot(video_games, aes(x = Year)) + geom_histogram(stat = 'count') + lims(x = c(1995, 2017))`

Comment: `ggplot(video_games, aes(x = factor(Year))) + geom_histogram(stat = 'count') ` should help.

Comment: @Duck gives an error, not a correct solution

Comment: So please `dput(video_games)` an include in your question so that it is easy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `scale_x_continuous` with the `breaks` argument:

```
ggplot(...) +
  ... +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1995:2016)
```

Comment: Nope it removed all the labels instead

Comment: If the labels disappeared, it means your `Year` variable is viewed as continuous and not discrete. See updated answer - using `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_discrete` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ggplot(video_games, aes(x = year)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(video_games$year)) +
  coord_flip()
```

`coord_flip` is there because you will have a lot of 'long' labels on x-axis. If you dont want to flip you can rotate:

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```